# Can I integrate my Dialogflow agent into Wordpress with NO plugins and NO suscription to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot

I have a client that maintains that it should be posible, and I couldn't find anything.

When I take the Dialogflow Text Integrations html code and put it into my private server, it works like a charm.
When I put it into a Widget (footer) or directly as plain html custom code, it shows the link to a function that I supose must be executed.

This is the code

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
    <df-messenger intent="WELCOME" chat-title="Agent" agent-id="a7bbf18b-21b8-4ae3-9aa8-5a72b8fd0d4c" language-code="es">
    <style>
        df-messenger {
            --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #62b3be;
            --df-messenger-chat-background-color: rgb(206, 221, 226);
            --df-messenger-font-color: white;
            --df-messenger-font-size: 30px;
            --df-messenger-send-icon: #878fac;
            --df-messenger-user-message: rgb(153, 182, 176);
            --df-messenger-bot-message: rgb(136, 165, 159);
        }
      </style>
    </df-messenger>
```

In my localhost page it looks like this
[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7bMK.png)

This is how I put the code into a Custom HTML block in Wordpress
[how I do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDKWF.png)

This is what it shows
[When it should be showing a Dialogflow Button, it shows a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nKWW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated post to clarify the issue. Thank you.

Comment: According to Wordpress [code support documentation](https://wordpress.com/support/code/#javascript), you can not add Javascript without plugins for security measures.